# Mule: building embedded application with Maven

Tags: maven, mule

Is there a way to build a Mule application as an embedded stand-alone jar using Maven (possibly with a help of Mule maven plugin)?

How the pom should be configured if so?

The MuleSoft documentation says that you can create an embedded app by adding all the dependencies manually. But I hope there is a way to automate this task.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Maven application and depend only on [org.mule.distributions:mule:jar:embedded:3.7.0](https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/distributions/mule/3.7.0/mule-3.7.0-embedded.jar) but this won't create an app with all Mule classes inside of it, which I think is a useful approach (though I don't understand your scenario).

If you need all dependencies to be packaged in your application bundle you can use [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to include all dependencies in a zip file. First add the plugin configuration to your pom like this:

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And add an assembly.xml file in your project root directory containing this:

```
<assembly>
    <id>application-name</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried this. It's actually building the application but when you trying running it it fails on missing dependencies. So, you actually need to run your app in order to find out what libraries are missing. And you need to do this one by one for each dependency. And then you'll find that Mule required very special versions of the dependencies, otherwise the app will be crashing. This makes the process of building the  embedded app extremely complex.

Comment: You are right, there are lots of other dependencies. What about using Maven assembly plugin to create a war containing all the dependencies? Or creating a zip file with all dependencies in a lib directory?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.